# Some discussions don't have a flag link

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, spam, discussions-space

This morning I came across two posts in the CI/CD collective's discussions that are clearly spam ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions/77295781/navigating-the-path-to-success-inspirational-career-journeys) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions/77295801/breaking-free-from-chronic-technical-debt-a-journey-to-technological-liberat)).

I'd usually just flag them and move on with my day, but for some reason, the "flag" link isn't where it's supposed to be, next to the "follow" link:
[image]

At first, I thought it was a quirk of discussions without replies, but that isn't it. The same collective has other discussions without replies (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions/77131900/container-registry-not-showing-all-the-pushed-images-in-gitlab-relevant-section)), that do have the "flag" link.

Comment: Can reproduce, as a workaround I added the HTML for the flag button manually in the page (through the devtools) and was then able to flag.

Comment: At this point, both discussions are indicated as having been flagged. While moderators are shown when viewing the discussion page that a flag has been raised, those flags go to CMs, not moderators. I suspect the system is not showing the "flag" button because the discussion has already been flagged. However, not showing the flag button is counter-intuitive, counter to every other control on the site, and doesn't allow for the normal removal of such things as spam as the result of multiple flags.

Comment: I've now deleted both of these spam discussions. However, I saw no method of deleting them as spam, which is normally done by a moderator raising a spam flag. Ironically, now that they are deleted, the "Flag" option is shown. There also doesn't appear to be a method of undeleting the discussion. The "delete" option for a discussion does not appear to be presented to moderators unless the discussion has been flagged.

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug, the intended behavior is that a post can be flagged by multiple people. @Makyen For a non-flagged post, the delete button is found on the "edit" screen. CMs and mods have the same permissions for the Discussions moderation functions. At this time, there is not an undelete option.

Comment: @Berthold Thanks. I would have never thought to look for the "delete" button on the "Edit" page. I'll mention it to the other mods. BTW: Are CM's *notified* in some way about Discussions flags? I don't need details. I just want to make sure that we don't need be polling the discussions looking for flags. As far as I've seen, moderators aren't notified in any way (i.e., the flag shows, in a non-standard way, when viewing the Discussion, but doesn't show in the moderator flag dashboard, or at least I didn't see a flag category for them).

Comment: @Makyen I added some content on the Moderators Team with details about Discussions moderation.

Answer (score 6):

The fix for this is done and will be deployed soon. Any user will be able to flag a post or reply in Discussions, regardless of whether another user has already flagged it (which is the intended behavior).

Comment: Can I assume this isn't pushed yet? (see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions/77428698/elevate-your-fitness-game-at-the-state-of-the-art-gym-in-greater-noida)

Comment: Hmm... The deleted discussion linked in @Mureinik's comment is still visible to me, despite the deletion notice saying "(Viewable by the post author and collective Admins)". I'm guessing there are collective permission overrides for me (and Catija?) that haven't been removed yet – I sent in a Contact form message about a related issue (I can still see the AudioBubble test collective) a while back, but haven't heard back yet.